# Another many-to-many relationship question

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, many-to-many

My database includes a Customer and a Subcategories table.
Customers can belong to one-or-more Subcategories (and of course there are one-or-more Customers for any Subcategory).
I wonder which is the best solution to link these tables that share a many-to-many relationship:

- A "standard" junction CustomerSubcategory table that includes just two fields: CustomerID  (PK, FK) and SubcategoryID  (PK, FK), or
- A CustomerSubcategoryDetail table that would also include a CustomerSubcategoryDetailID (PK), as well as the SubcategoryID (PK, FK) and CustomerID (FK) fields.

Any advice?

Cheers, Corbex

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the additional PK on the junction table adds any value. Will you ever have to look up the value(s) in that table *without* being able to identify them by Customer and/or SubCategoryID? Will the CustomerSubCategoryDetailID value be used anywhere else?

An interesting discussion ensued on my blog when I [complained about folks knee-jerking an IDENTITY column onto every single table](https://sqlblog.org/2010/02/08/bad-habits-to-kick-putting-an-identity-column-on-every-table). Some folks made some good arguments for having an OrderDetailID column on the OrderDetails table. Do any of these situations apply to you?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need for a third column with a customersubcategoryid; therefore, I would go with the first option. The extra column is not going to  give you any advantage in any of your joins. You won't even use it.

Answer (score 1):

Go with your first choice.  Make sure that you create a key that includes both columns and enforces uniqueness.  That way you'll never need a separate primary key to distinguish between otherwise identical rows.

There is a additional benefit in having both columns in the unique key.  Queries that need to perform a lookup by the first column can use the index, but they never need to read the data rows because the index already contains the second column.